# How to use list Comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I tried simple pattern program using python.but I tried to my code convert to list comprehension code.but its showing invalid syntax error .how to solve it

pattera.py

```
# Without List Compreshion
class Apattern:
    def __init__(self,row,column):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

    def a_pattern(self):


        for i in range(self.row):
            for j in range(self.column):
                if i == 0 or j == 0 or j == self.column-1 or i == 2:
                    print("*",end=" ")
                else:
                    # print(j,end=" ")
                    print(" ",end=" ")
            print()


a1 = Apattern(5,5)
a1.a_pattern()
```

patterna.py

```
class Apattern:
    def __init__(self,row,column):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column

    def a_pattern(self):

        data = [print("*",end=" ") print() for i in range(self.row) for j in range(self.column) if i == 0 or j == 0 or j == self.column-1 or i == 2 else print(" ",end=" ") ]
        print(data)

a1 = Apattern(5,5)
a1.a_pattern()
```

Comment: Do you actually need a list here? List comps are for creating lists, you don't seem to need one here.

Comment: you have twice print() in list comprehension, you need to remove second

Comment: List-comprehension are useful for functions which actually return a value, `print` returns None, and by doing list comprehension over it, you create a list of `None`

Comment: but I have a doubt In my logic code .how to change list compreshion code.can you give me code for list compreshion using nested forloop and nested if condition.

Comment: for i in range(5):
 for j in range(5):
  if (i==0 or j==0 or j==col-1 or i==2):
   print("*",end=" ")
  else:
   print(" ",end=" ")

Comment: @smithhari, please don't use list-comprehension here. Your first solution is fine if it's working good.

Comment: no actually I tried it list compreshion practice for sample code.can you give explain .why  don't use list-comprehension here.

Comment: Read my first comment.

Comment: List comprehensions are for *creating lists*, you aren't creating a list and you shouldn't use a list comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others said, list comprehension is not suitable here, it is used for the situation you want to get a list, but here you just want to print out.

But if you insist on this, I can provide you two version:

1. we can use list comprehension to generate a result list, the element is each line:

```
def a_pattern(self):
    # generate the result list of each line
    result = [' '.join(['*'] * self.column)
               if i in (0, 2) else (' ' * (self.column * 2 - 3)).join('**')
               for i in range(self.row)]

    for line in result:
        print(line)
```

2. if you insist call `print` in list comprehension based on your logic, you can try this hackish-way:

```
def a_pattern(self):
    # print logic in list comprehension
    _ = [print("*", end=" ") or j == self.column - 1 and print('')
            if i == 0 or j == 0 or j == self.column - 1 or i == 2
            else print(" ", end=" ") or j == self.column - 1 and print('')
            for i in range(self.row) for j in range(self.column)]
```

I will explain it here:
the key point and most difficult part is that we have to `print('')` after every line(when `j == self.column - 1`).
Here I use the lazy evaluation in `and/or`:
`j == self.column - 1 and print('')`
when `j` not the last index, `print('')` will not be called, otherwise, it will call `print('')`

> Notice: it is just a study of list comprehension and lazy evaluation, don't use this in your code.
>
> With some hackish, we can even create variables or add `break` logic in list comprehension, but do it just for fun. : )

Comment: like @Austin said, list comprehension is inefficient here, I post this because you said you want to practice with list compreshion : )

Comment: like @DeveshKumarSingh said, we only want the generation process of list comprehension, in my code, `_` is waste here, create a list of `None`